# mysql SELECT where like and like

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, sql-like

I have a column called `papers` in a table called `products` that has values like this :

"1,2,3,4,5,6" and in other row it has like this "3,4,5"

I want to launch this query with php,

`SELECT * from products where papers like "%5%" AND papers like "%3%" and papers like "%4%"`

TL;DR

I want to select a column that has multiple strings, ignoring the order

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) is also worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
select * 
from products 
where find_in_set('3', papers) and find_in_set('4', papers) and find_in_set('5', papers)
```

Note that your question suggests a flawed database design. You should not be storing multiple integer values in a single string column. Instead, you should have each integer value in a separate row, probably in another table, that would refer to the main table through a foreign key constraint. Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Comment: emm I could have done it with the same way I sent my code, but I want to do it dynamically with php, without repeating 'and'

Comment: @MMoh: (1) your code is not safe, as it would match `3` against a string like `1,2,31`. `find_in_set()` avoids that trap. (2) I don't think you can do this with a single condition.

Comment: they actually are not numbers, ```SELECT * from products where find_in_set('agreement_to_sell', papers) AND find_in_set('land_register', papers) AND find_in_set('re_promotion', papers)``` here is my real query, just wanted to simplify things

Comment: if you want to do it "dynamically with php" then repeating the and is easy.  if it is not, then this is really a php question and you need to show your php code

Comment: @GMB yours is a better solution than mine tbh, I will try to use it in my code, Regards.